# I am unable to add a reference to System.Windows.Media in my .net 3.5 project

Tags: .net

I'm using VS 2008, with .net 3.5. I need access to System.Windows.Media.Color, but when I try to "Add Reference...", System.Windows.Media is not listed.

I'm not sure where to go next since the MSDN documentation seems to think I should have access to it by default, and doesn't give any additional information on how to include it.

Just adding "using System.Windows.Media" turns up an error saying I'm probably missing a reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.aspx

It's in the PresentationCore.dll.  (Look at the very top of the page).

Namespaces aren't always in individual .dll files, a lot of times they are bundled as a larger dll like this.

Answer (score 0):

Add PresentationCore, which you should find under the .NET tab of Add Reference dialog box.